# Mongoid connection pool on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I have an application deployed on heroku. Sometimes background process raises the following error: "The task failed because of an error: could not obtain connection within 5.0 seconds. The max pool size is currently 1; consider increasing the pool size or timeout."

How can I increase `pool size` or the `timeout`?
Unfortunately I can't find anything useful in Mongoid documentation and sources.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the pool size in `mongoid.yml`:

```
production:
    pool_size: 5
```

Details [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoid/uA6K9oFx-A8).

Comment: Not for Mongoid 3, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoid/yesQ2AHtPyI

Comment: what is the ideal size for the pool?